# emit, retorna undefined vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify

Al momento de editar, estoy enviando un emit con la data para que se actualice la etiqueta del campo en la lista.
Al hacer un console log, veo que el emit, si contiene la data que estoy enviando,, pero desde el componente list, que es donde hago las escucha del emit, me arroja undefined.

acá unas imagenes para acompañar la explicación.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Codigo

Aqui mi codigo del handleAdd

```
async handleAdd() {
const valid = await this.$refs.form.validate();
if (!valid) return
try {
/* TODO añadir emit para enviar data a atualizar a la lista de campos.*/
bus.$emit("add", {
...this.field,
...this.index
});
console.log('emitField', this.field)
console.log('emitIndex', this.index)
this.$emit("close");
this.handleReset();
} catch (e) {
console.log(e)
}
}
```

acá el list donde escucho el evento

```
mounted() {
this.visible = true)
bus.$on('add', ({ index, field })=> {
console.log('listenIndex',index)
console.log('listenField',field)
this.index = index
this.field = field
})
},
```

El emit, finalmente deberia actualizar la lista de campos.

#### Compoenentes detallados en CodePen

Acá los componentes completos en caso de que quieran verlos en mas detalle.
Espero haber detallado bien , para ver si pueden ayudarme a ver en que me estoy cayendo.
Saludos

[MilestoneFieldsEdit.vue](https://codepen.io/fmoraless/pen/ExoLjRp)

[MilestoneFieldsList.vue](https://codepen.io/fmoraless/pen/KKZRpBq)

Answer (score 1):

El error está en como envías la información al `$emit`, ya que estás aplicando [desestructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), por lo tanto lo que te llega al `$on` son las propiedades del objeto `field`.

desestructuras el objeto `field`

```
bus.$emit("add", {
 ...this.field,
 ...this.index
});
```

intentas acceder a una propiedad `field` dentro del objeto `field` lo cuál es `undefined`

```
bus.$on('add', ({ index, field })=> {
 console.log('acceder a la propiedad field ',field ) // undefined

})
```

podrías acceder a los valores del objeto con

```
bus.$on('add', ({ index, label,sort})=> {
 console.log('acceder a la propiedad label',label) // ok
 console.log('acceder a la propiedad sort',sort) // ok

})
```

Comment: entiendo. Ahora que ya teniendo esta data intento pasarlo a la lista
`
    mounted() {
    //bus.$on('open-update-milestone-field', ()=> this.visible = true)
    bus.$on('add', (field)=> {
      console.log('acceder a la propiedad index',field.sort) // ok
      console.log('acceder a la propiedad field',field.label) // ok
      this.index = field.sort
      this.field = field.label
    })
  },
es la respuesta a mi pregunta. pero si me puede ayudar con esto ultimo plis